# Checar elemento UNIQUE antes de inserí-lo

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela em um banco de dados MySQL onde um de seus campos (e-mail) é `UNIQUE`, quando estiver inserindo um registro eu devo realizar primeiro um `select` verificando se existe um registro cujo campo e-mail coincida com o e-mail que quero inserir (lembrando que o campo é UNIQUE) ou devo tratar a exceção gerada? Estou usando PDO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não faça isso. Está criando um [*race condition*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101). Você verifica se está ok, outro usuário (ou o mesmo em outra sessão) muda o estado do banco, ou seja, um valor que era único, não é mais, aí o código vai inserir na certeza que ele é único e ele já não é mais, e vai dar erro. Então se vai verificar algo que não garante nada, não verifique. Trate da exceção gerada, esse é um dos principais motivos para existirem exceções (ou códigos de erro).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

Ricardo, se vc for apenar fazer a inserção sem fazer nenhum tipo de validação... do tipo o e-mail já esta cadastrado porem os dados são diferente ou o e-mail já esta cadastrado tenho que avisar isto ao usuário, voce pode usar o INSERT IGNORE que vai tentar fazer a inserção porém se o email já estiver cadastrado ele vai ignora a inserção.
Mas para que isto ocorra seu campo EMAIL tem que esta como UNIQUE.

Acho que isto vai resolver o seu problema.